# ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC sql query bug

Tags: dynamic, innodb, myisam, compression

this is the query :

```
CREATE TABLE `pedidos_detalle` (
  `Id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `fk_pedido` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `fk_articulo` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `precio` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cantidad` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `importe` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `detalle` text,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=16503 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC;
```

The result of  this query is the error message : **#1005 - Can't create table 'netlogiq_acros.pedidos_detalle' (errno: 1478)**
If i removed the `ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC` it works, but I know don't what will be the effects on the feature . Or if changed the InnoDB to MyISAM it also works. but still I do not know what will be effects. Can someone help me how to manage this ? explain me the differencet between myIsam and Innodb and for what reason I should use ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC or COMPRESSED ? thx

Answer (score 0):

innoDB and MyIsam are Table formats. MyIsam is the older on and has been standard up until mysql 5.5. which version are you using? you can read about the advantages and disadvantages of both on wikipedia. i would recommend to use innoDB.

the meaning of the setting ROW_FORMAT = DYNAMIC is explained here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/innodb-plugin/1.0/en/innodb-row-format-dynamic.html

but why would want this setting to be applied? as far as i understood, you do not know what ist exactly does? in this case i would prefer the working solution that i also do not understand over the not working solution that i still do not understand. Or do you have an external requirement?

I hope this helps.